# Magento 2 - How to Overwrite Default Translation Core en_US Dictionary Package

Tags: magento2, localisation, package, i18n

I want to change the word **"Magento"** to **"Magento 2 CE"** for the **Default Translation Core en_US Dictionary Package**.
How to achieve this **without overwrite Magento's core functionality directly at** *vendor/magento/< module-name >/i18n/en_US.csv* and what is the best way to do this?

I need this only for the adminhtml Core and Custom Modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a en_US.csv file under your theme like

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Name>/<Theme_Name>/i18n/en_US.csv
```